# Outlook VBA call to excel causes crash

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm struggling with outlook / excel vba code to correctly end each time it's run.

My current script runs everytime I receive a new mail. All mails on this address is a registration from a website (wordpress) and contains a standard format as shown here:

```
Navn: John Doe 

Deltakelse: I/we arrive on friday

Spesielle mathensyn: some random text here

Epost: john.doe@emailprovider.com

Kommentar: Some random text here

Time: mai 25, 2017 at 6:02 pm
IP Adresse: 127.0.0.1
Contact Form URL: https://mysite.wordpress.com/
Sendt av en ubekreftet besøkende til ditt nettsted.
```

I want to extract the info and automatically update the RVSP.xlsx document (in addition to sending a autoreply mail which works good!). I have verified that I manage to extract the text I want, but every other time the script crash/stops and I have to manually end it. I suspect I am not closing the excel application correctly, but I have tried to read myself up on this and I'm not getting any wiser. Can someone please help me?

This is the outlook vba code

```
Public Const ColNavn As Integer = 1
Public Const ColDeltakelse As Integer = 2
Public Const ColMathensyn As Integer = 3
Public Const ColEpost As Integer = 4
Public Const ColKommentar As Integer = 5
Public Const ColRegistrert As Integer = 6

Sub SendNew(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   Dim Reg1 As Object
    Dim M1 As Object
    Dim M As Object
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim navn As String
    Dim deltakelse As String
    Dim mathensyn As String
    Dim kommentar As String

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With Reg1
       .Pattern = "(([\w-\.]*\@[\w-\.]*)\s*)"
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Global = False
    End With

If Reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
        For Each M In M1
           strAddress = M.SubMatches(1)
        Next
End If

With Reg1
       .Pattern = "(Navn[:]([\w-\s]*)\s*)Deltakelse"
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Global = False
    End With

If Reg1.Test(Item.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Item.Body)
        For Each M In M1
           navn = M.SubMatches(1)
        Next
End If

deltakelse = "testDeltakelse"
mathensyn = "mathensyn test2"
kommentar = "kommentar med fire ord"

Call Svar(navn, deltakelse, mathensyn, strAddress, kommentar)

 Dim objMsg As MailItem
 Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("E:\Dropbox\Bryllup\Mail\mal.oft")

 objMsg.Recipients.Add strAddress

 ' Copy the original message subject
 objMsg.Subject = "Takk for svar"

' use for testing
' objMsg.Display

 objMsg.Send

 End Sub

Sub Svar(navn As String, deltakelse As String, mathensyn As String, epost As String, kommentar As String)

  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim ExcelWkBk As Excel.Workbook
  Dim FileName As String
  Dim PathName As String

  PathName = "E:\Dropbox\Bryllup\Mail\"
  FileName = "RSVP.xlsx"

  Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  With xlApp
    '.Visible = True         ' This slows your macro but helps during debugging
    Set ExcelWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName)
    With ExcelWkBk

      ' Add Excel VBA code to update workbook here
        Dim RowNext As Integer

        With Sheets("Ark1")     '   Replace with the name of your worksheet
            ' This finds the bottom row with a value in column A.  It then adds 1 to get
            ' the number of the first unused row.
            RowNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With

        With Sheets("Ark1")     '   Replace with the name of your worksheet

            .Cells(RowNext, ColNavn).Value = navn
            .Cells(RowNext, ColDeltakelse).Value = deltakelse
            .Cells(RowNext, ColMathensyn).Value = mathensyn
            .Cells(RowNext, ColEpost).Value = epost
            .Cells(RowNext, ColKommentar).Value = kommentar
            With .Cells(RowNext, ColRegistrert)
                .Value = Now()
                ' This format means the time is stored and I can access it but it
                'is not displayed.  Change to "mm/dd/yy" or whatever you like.
                .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
            End With
            'RowNext = RowNext + 1   ' Ready for next loop

        End With
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
  End With
  Set ExcelWkBk = Nothing
  xlApp.Quit
  Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I use outlook 2016 and excel 2016.

Comment: Change both occurrences of `Sheets("Ark1")` to be `.Sheets("Ark1")`, and change `Rows.Count` to `.Rows.Count`

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked!